# How to find the dimension of kernel $f$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions

Consider a linear map $f∈L(Π2(\Bbb R),\Bbb R^2) $ whose matrix $f_{G,B}$ in the basis $\mathcal B$ of $\prod_2(\Bbb R)$ and

$G=\{(1,1) , (1,-1)\}$ of $\Bbb R^2$ is

$$f_{G,B} = \begin{pmatrix}
-4 & -8 \\ 7 & 4\\ 5 & 0
\end{pmatrix} ^T$$
(This is suppose to be a $\Bbb R^{2x3}$ matrix)

From the information i need to find: dim ker $f$

Im a bit confused am i suppose to use the matrix of $f_{G.B}$?
*From a previous part of the question i found the rank$f =2$ if that helps at all.

To find the kernel i multiplies the $fG,B$ matrix by $(x, y)^T$ and equated it to $(0,0)^T$ and solved this using the row reduced matrix . So I got $x1 + 1/2x3 = 0$ and $x2 + x3 = 0$  and let $x3= λ$. Therfore $x1 = -1/2λ$ , $x2 = -λ$ and $x3 = λ$

Im not sure if what i did so far is correct. I think i need to use span, but i dont know how exactly.

Would really appreciate your help, thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are done, a basis for the $\ker f$ is given by $(-1/2,-1,1)$, as you can directly check, thus the dimension of $\ker f$ is 1.

Note that to find the dimension of $\ker f$ (and thus also of Im(f)), it is sufficient to refer to the rank of the RREF matrix, we don't need to solve the system if we are not interested in finding a basis.

Comment: So if i found the rank to = 2 how can i use this?

Comment: thanks for your help btw

Comment: refer to the rank-nullity theorem dim ker = n - r https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem

Comment: @Lily You are welcome!

Comment: @Lily Note also that in this case also without RREF, since we have a 2-by-3 matrix, $1\le rank \le 2$ and since the rows are not multiple we can immeditely conclude that r=2 and dim ker =1.

Comment: thanks again. I have a bit of a problem though, for some reason im getting the answer wrong. Did i calculate the rank wrong? or am i not suppose to use the martix f_G.B? Because it says calculate the rank and dimker of f and i just assumed they meant the f_G,B matrix that has been given @gimusi

Comment: @Lily Sorry maybe I lost something, let check again. What to you mean by $\prod_2(\Bbb R)$?

Comment: im pretty sure that's a second degree polynomial

Comment: Ok I’m going to check again! I will let know asap.

Comment: Your calculation seems correct indeed the basis vector for the ker works, why you say that it’s wrong? which solution has been given?

Comment: OK thank you so much, i genuinely appreciate it! @gimusi

Comment: I havent been given a solution, its a question that you just type the answer to and they tell you if its correct or not

Comment: and you have typed that the dim ker=1, right?